Ruby strptime beginning and end of string
Is it possible to parse a string with Ruby Date.strptime that constrains the beginning and end of the string? What I'm looking for is a more strict way to parse strings as dates that will throw an error if a string doesn't match exactly. For example, with the string "SEPTEMBER 8, 2016", if I use Date.strptime(str, "%B %d, %y"), it will return the date Tue, 08 Sep 2020, when the year should be 2016. Is there a way to constrain strptime so that it has to match the entire string, like with ^ and $ in regexes? I want it to raise an error with these sorts of strings rather than returning the wrong result.

The code returns the year 2020, because there is a y in the format for strptime instead of a Y. y matches two digits as a year, Y four digits.
And when changing the format to %B %d, %Y then it returns a date in the year 2016 as expected:
require 'date'

string = "SEPTEMBER 8, 2016"

Date.strptime(string, "%B %d, %y")
#=> #<Date: 2020-09-08 ((2459101j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Date.strptime(string, "%B %d, %Y")
#=> #<Date: 2016-09-08 ((2457640j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>


Yeah, I'm aware of the difference between %y and %Y. The problem here is that I'm dealing with arbitrary date formats, so I'm hoping to test them against different patterns and when one pattern fails try the next one.

You can use %C flag to require a two digit century:
>> Date.strptime("September 08, 2016", "%B %d, %C%y")
=> #<Date: 2016-09-08 ((2457640j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

>> Date.strptime("September 08, 20", "%B %d, %C%y")
(irb):4:in `strptime': invalid date (Date::Error)


As others have noted, the format you're looking for is "%B %d, %Y".
To answer the original question: strptime always matches from the beginning of the string, no need to specify anything to get that behavior. It will consume characters until it has found a match, confirmed there is no match or run out of characters. It doesn't care about remaining characters in the string. Usually this is not a problem, but if it's important for your use case, you could assert that the original string and the parsed date (reformatted using the same format string) are the same:
format = "%B %d, %Y"
date = Date.strptime(string, format)
formatted_date = date.strftime(format)
raise unless formatted_date == string

